# Seeking data on graduate admissions, DoED

Tags: data-request, api, data.gov, education, data

I've found the troves of data from the department of education on undergraduate admissions. School acceptance rates, ACT / SATs, etc.

Is there any such data for graduate schools or programs? For example, GRE / GMAT data, or simply acceptance rates. Any help would be greatly appreciated!